Azure Java App Service Fails to Start Due to "Tag value too large" Error in Application Insights
I am encountering an issue where our Azure Java App Service is taking an excessively long time to start, eventually leading to a timeout. The error appears to be related to a tag size limit in the Azure Web App's Activity log. The specific error message is:
Tag value too large. Following tag value 'InstrumentationKey=[MASKED];IngestionEndpoint=https://germanywestcentral-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://germanywestcentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=[MASKED]' exceeded the maximum length. Maximum allowed length for tag value - '256' characters.

We are deploying our application using Terraform with the azurerm provider, version ~> 3.115.0.
I've searched extensively for solutions but have not found any relevant discussions or fixes. I have a few questions regarding this issue:

Why is there an attempt to set such a long tag value? Is this expected behavior when configuring Application Insights with the App Service?

How can I fix or reduce the tag size? Are there any configurations or best practices to prevent this from happening?

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it?


Below is the relevant portion of our Terraform configuration for the Web App:
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "[MASKED]" {
  name                = "app-${local.app_naming_component}"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.[MASKED].name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.[MASKED].id

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image_name   = "${var.image_name}:${var.image_tag}"
      docker_registry_url = "https://${data.azurerm_container_registry.shared.login_server}"
    }

    container_registry_use_managed_identity = "true"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY             = data.azurerm_application_insights.[MASKED].instrumentation_key
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING      = data.azurerm_application_insights.[MASKED].connection_string
    ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_STATSBEAT_DISABLED     = true
    WEBSITES_PORT                              = 8080
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE                     = var.environment
    DOCKER_ENABLE_CI                           = "true"
  }
}

And here is the Terraform configuration for Application Insights and the Log Analytics workspace:
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "[MASKED]" {
  name                = "log-${local.app_naming_component}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.[MASKED].name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.[MASKED].location
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
  tags                = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "[MASKED]" {
  name                 = "appi-${local.app_naming_component}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.[MASKED].name
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.[MASKED].location
  workspace_id         = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.[MASKED].id
  application_type     = "java"
  retention_in_days    = 30
  daily_data_cap_in_gb = 1
}

I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations to address this issue.

Do you need the tags = var.tags line in your Terraform config file?

"How can I fix or reduce the tag size?" - You can remove and edit tags in the Azure Portal.

We don't necessarily need the tags = var.tags line at this point. The tagging issue is related to the App Service rather than the azurerm_log_analytics_workspace. Does the tag on the Log Analytics Workspace influence the tag created on the App Service?

No, the tags on the Log Analytics Workspace do not directly influence the tags created on the App Service. Tags applied to different Azure resources are independent unless specifically referenced or inherited within your configuration, which is not the case here.

The issue you are facing is related to a tag value exceeding the maximum allowed length for a tag on the App Service. The problematic tag mentioned in the error (InstrumentationKey=[MASKED];IngestionEndpoint=...) is related to Application Insights settings on the App Service, not tags set in the azurerm_log_analytics_workspace resource.


Tag value too large. Following tag value 'InstrumentationKey=[MASKED];IngestionEndpoint=https://germanywestcentral-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://germanywestcentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=[MASKED]' exceeded the maximum length. Maximum allowed length for tag value - '256' characters.


If possible, use the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY environment variable instead of the full APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING. The instrumentation key is much shorter and usually sufficient for basic Application Insights functionality.

Look through the app_settings in the Terraform configuration and remove any settings that are not necessary.
.tf file:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  version = "~> 3.115.0"
}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

# Service Plan
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

# Application Insights
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "example-ai"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

# Log Analytics Workspace
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "example-log-workspace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30

  # Tags have been removed to avoid exceeding tag length limits
}

# Linux Web App
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "example-web-app"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image_name   = "example-image"
      docker_registry_url = "https://example.com"
    }

    container_registry_use_managed_identity = true
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY             = azurerm_application_insights.example.instrumentation_key
    # Using instrumentation key instead of a long connection string
    ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_STATSBEAT_DISABLED     = "true"
    WEBSITES_PORT                              = 8080
  }

  # Example of applying short, meaningful tags
  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
    Owner       = "TeamName"
  }
}

Intialized:

Deployed:

